# Connect front-end with backend

Tags: java, spring, jsp

My controller is

@RestController public class MainRestController {

```
@Autowired
private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainRestController.class);

@RequestMapping("/")
public String newHome(Model Employee){
    return "newHome";
}

// call http://<host>/newHome.jspjsp or just http://<host>/hello
/*
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newHome(Model employee) {
    employee.addAttribute("myObject", new MyObject("helloWorld"));
    return "newHome";
}
```

*/
    @RequestMapping(value = "/employee", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public JSONObject getEmployees(){

```
    return employeeDAO.getAllEmployees();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/employee/{empName}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })

public JSONObject getEmployee(@PathVariable("empName") String empName) {
    return employeeDAO.getEmployee(empName);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/employee", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})

public Employee addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp) {

    return employeeDAO.addEmployee(emp);

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/employee", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public Employee updateEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp) {

    return employeeDAO.updateEmployee(emp);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/employees/{empName}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public void deleteEmployee(@PathVariable("empName") String empName) {
    employeeDAO.deleteEmployee(empName);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/newHome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Employee newEmployee(){
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setEmpName("newHome");
    return employee;
} }
```

And my java file is:

public class ReadExcelFileAndStore {

```
public List getTheFileAsObject(String filePath){

    List <Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));

        // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

        int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
        //loop through each of the sheets
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSheets; i++) {

            // Get first sheet from the workbook
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);

            // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                // Get Each Row
                Row row = rowIterator.next();

                //Leaving the first row alone as it is header

                if (row.getRowNum() == 0)
                    continue;

                // For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                Employee employee = new Employee();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    int columnIndex = cell.getColumnIndex();

                    switch (columnIndex + 1) {

                        case 1:
                            employee.setEmpName(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            employee.setExtCode((int) cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            break;
                    }
                }
                employeeList.add(employee);
            }
        }
        file.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return employeeList;
} }
```

I followed some web on serving static content in controller and added required dependencies needed for JSP and tags included in JSP files. But still I colud not connect my front-end with my back-end even though I have JSP files to link. what should I need to add more so as to connect my front-end with the back-end. Please anyone knows share your answers. Thank you

Comment: Looks like you barfed code onto the page! At least distil out only the necessary sections, and then take the care to format them to be readable, and make your question clear and readable. If you don't care, why should anybody else?

Comment: @Stewart Please have a look at the given answer below. As the answer suggests me to provide "fully runnable code" I edited my question and pasted all my codings.

Comment: @Elli But (a) it is not well-formatted and difficult to read, and (b) it contains a ton of inapplicable stuff; for example, your question has nothing to do with `XLS` sheet, or iterating `Employee` objects, but you have included all this. It makes it difficult to see what the actual situation is. Please read this help guide .. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a folder called resources inside your src/main folder. Create a new folder named as static or public and place your html pages inside static or public folder. If you start with index page you don't need to create a separate mapping. Hope this is the answer you are looking for. For more knowledge refer his link: 
https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot

Comment: This is the exact answer that I am looking for!

Answer (score 1):

First of all your question is not clear. You have not specified what exactly is going wrong.
Second, please give a fully runnable code so that we can run it from our side.

Finally, I am guessing that the issue you are facing is that your JSP is not linking to you java class.

For that you need to annotate your class as a controller using @Controller so that spring knows who is handling the request.
Also, we use @ModelAttribute to link the front end to the underlying java code.

A very detailed tutorial example is given below.
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/